# COPY bulk insert with STDIN

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Hi I'm trying to use COPY command from PHP (Laravel)

`DB::statement("COPY table_name FROM '".$file."' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER")`

But if fails because of the `superuser` rights:

> must be superuser or a member of the pg_read_server_files role to COPY from a file
>
> HINT:  Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone

So I was trying to find how to do the same thing with `STDIN` from PHP, but only found examples from command line.

So I'm looking on how to use COPY with STDIN with PHP? Or maybe there is an alternative way to BULK insert 50K+ records.

P.S. I can't add `superuser` ROLE to the user, because the DB is hosted on DigitalOcean, and they decline to give `superuser` access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STDIN` is a pointer to file. See [stdin(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdin.3.html):

> Each of these symbols is a [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) macro of type pointer to *FILE*, and can be used with functions like [fprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html) or [fread(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html).

So, you [can](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php) open `STDIN` as a file.

```php
<?php  
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');  
DB::statement("COPY table_name FROM '".$stdin."' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER")
?>
```

P.S. 
DO's security team is right: you shouldn't use `superuser` role for regular tasks. Neither on the DO's servers nor anywhere else.

Comment: This won't work if Postgres resides on a remote server.